# Manual refresh in elasticsearch does not seem to take effect instantly

Tags: elasticsearch, testing

I have alot of unit tests that use an actual instance of elasticsearch. Currently between every test the index is deleted and recreated like this:

```
await client.indices.delete({ index });
await client.indices.create({ index, body: { settings, mappings } });
```

However, this is making the tests super slow. I tried to speed it up by emptying the indexes rather than recreating them between every single test, like this:

```
await client.indices.refresh({ index }, { request_timeout: timeout });
await client.deleteByQuery({ index, body: { query: { match_all: {} } } });
await client.indices.refresh({ index }, { request_timeout: timeout });
```

This is indeed much faster, but in some cases I am getting errors using this method but I don't understand why. In which situation would these two methods yield different results? The strange thing is that for one of the tests that fails, it fails at this assertion:

```
t.ok(result.score < 1);
```

It turns out that when i delete and recreate the index between tests the score in that assertion is always `0.2876821`. However, when I empty and refresh the index after every test instead of recreating the index, then the scores vary. For instance, when I comment out all unit tests except the one with the above assertion, the test suddenly succeeds but the `score` varies between one of: `0.18232156`, `0.13353139`, `0.2876821`. This makes me think the refresh doesn't apply instantly and thus the searches yield different score values depending on which updates are "visible".

Does anyone know an explanation for this? I would also love to hear suggestions on how to speed up getting a clean index in different ways.